# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I have a logging configuration class , from there am injecting a logging filter class to the application.I need to pass 2 string arguments to the logging filter class constructor.But its failing with error

```
  "message" : "Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'LoggingFilter' defined in file \LoggingFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}"
```

Logging Configuration class

```
    @Configuration
public class LoggingConfiguration {

    @Value("${operation.name}")
    private String operationName;

    @Value("${source.name.ui}")
    private String sourceName;

    @Bean
    public LoggingFilter getLoggingFilter() {
        return new LoggingFilter (operationName,sourceName);
    }
}
```

This is my logging Filter class

```
 @Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {

    private String operationName;
    private String source;


    public LoggingFilter(String operationName,String source) {
        this.operationName = operationName;
        this.source = source;
    }
    }
```

How can i pass these variables into the filter class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message shows that it cannot create the `@Component` annotated bean since there is no bean of type `String` in the context that can be injected. You have two options: either providing the two missing constructor arguments as beans or to provide `LoggingFilter` as a bean via `@Bean`-annotation. Since you do aready provide a bean of type `LoggingFilter` in `LoggingConfiguration` you proceed as follows:

You try to create the bean twice, once via `@Bean` and once via `@Component`.
Please remove `@Component` annotation in `LoggingFilter` and move `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` to the `@Bean` annotated method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The question is "How can i pass these variables into the filter class ?". I showed a way how to pass the variables into the filter class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I improved my answer. However as a bean of type `LoggingFilter` is already in the context, I assumed that the author just unintentionally added `@Component` annotation to it. That is why I just answered to remove this annotation...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for sharing your feedback. If an answer just gets downvoted, it is sometimes hard o figure out why :-)